# How to test a function that is dependent on a variable?

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I am trying to unit test the following function. As you can see the function output is dependent on the value of count. What is the appropriate syntax and functions to be used to test this type of function? I am very new to Jest and javascript.

```
function greetings(){
    if(count == 0){ 
        return "Hello! I am here to assist you in picking your ideal Apple product! YAYYY :D! We can start off by selecting the type of Apple product you wish to buy";
    }else if(count == 1){
        return "Hello again! Once we get your budget I can narrow down options for your ideal product! Whats your max budget?";
    }else if(count == 2){
        return "Hello again my friend! Once we get your ideal device size I can narrow down options for your ideal product! Whats your ideal size for this device?";
    }
}
```

this is what I tried

```
test ('greetings message test', () => {
    expect(responses.greetings().toBe("Hello! I am here to assist you in picking your ideal Apple product! YAYYY :D! We can start off by selecting the type of Apple product you wish to buy" || "Hello again! Once we get your budget I can narrow down options for your ideal product! Whats your max budget?" || "Hello again my friend! Once we get your ideal device size I can narrow down options for your ideal product! Whats your ideal size for this device?"))

});
```

the test just fails. I am not sure what the correct approach is. Help would be very much appreciated.

Comment: I am unsure how `greetings()` is called by `responses.greetings()`. How is count set? Is it global? YOU might be testing the wrong thing. Hard to tell with your code.

Comment: Usually in a case like this it is a good idea to refactor greetings so that it accepts a count argument.

Comment: Easiest way is to add a pure function that actually take the count as a parameter so you can easily test it.

Comment: this will require changing a lot of the main code and there are many functions like this to test as well. It would be helpful to know if there is a way to pass a value of count to greetings when writing the test.

Comment: @epascarello exports.greetings = greetings is used to export the function.
const responses = require ("./responses") is used to import the function from the responses file.

I believe i have correct syntax to call the function via responses.greetings() as other functions that do not depend on an external variable have been tested successfully.

Comment: where and how `count` is declared?

Comment: count is declared on responses.js file. and is declared as var count = 0;

Comment: so set `count` and call `greetings`

Answer (score 0):

There are various approaches.

The first one is to add a pure function that is easy to test

```
var count = 0;

export function increment(){
  count++;
}

export function decrement(){
 count--;
}

export function greetings() {
  return getGreetings(count);
}

// function to test
export function getGreetings(c) {
    if(c == 0){ 
        return "Hello! I am here to assist you in picking your ideal Apple product! YAYYY :D! We can start off by selecting the type of Apple product you wish to buy";
    }else if(c == 1){
        return "Hello again! Once we get your budget I can narrow down options for your ideal product! Whats your max budget?";
    }else if(c == 2){
        return "Hello again my friend! Once we get your ideal device size I can narrow down options for your ideal product! Whats your ideal size for this device?";
    }
}
```

A second approach is to test the module as a whole (less unitary). You can do this by reseting the module in each test and calling the increment/decrement functions (or whatever you have in your code that changes the count) to set the count to the intended value

```
describe('responses', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
        // this will reset the module so when you use
        // const responses = require('./responses') it will get a fresh responses module with count = 0
        jest.resetModules()
    });

    it('test count 0', () => {
        const module = require('./responses');
        expect(module.greetings()).toBe('greeting for count 0');
    })
    it('test count 1', () => {
        const module = require('./responses');
        module.increment();
        expect(module.greetings()).toBe('greeting for count 1');
    })
    it('test count 2', () => {
        const module = require('./responses');
        module.increment();
        module.increment();
        expect(module.greetings()).toBe('greeting for count 2');
    })
    
})
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all **I strongly suggest what other users already said (e.g. add a pure function that actually take the count as a parameter so you can easily test it)** `BUT` if for unknown reasons you can't strictly change the implementation of the outside `var count`, my proposal is to slightly change what the implementation of `greetings` in this way:

```js
function greetings(_c){
    var innerCount = _c || count;
    if(innerCount === 0){ 
        return "Hello! I am here to assist you in picking your ideal Apple product! YAYYY :D! We can start off by selecting the type of Apple product you wish to buy";
    } else if(innerCount === 1){
        return "Hello again! Once we get your budget I can narrow down options for your ideal product! Whats your max budget?";
    } else if(innerCount === 2){
        return "Hello again my friend! Once we get your ideal device size I can narrow down options for your ideal product! Whats your ideal size for this device?";
    }
}
```

And then you can use inside the test something like this:

```js
expect(responses.greetings(0).toBe("Hello!...."))
```